# Embedded style overriding inline styles?

Tags: javascript, html, inline

So I have a button with embedded style and a function that changes the button's style via inline style to display:none. Problem is the embedded style seems to be overriding the inline style. So, the questions are:

- Aren't inline styles supposed to take precedence over embedded? Is there something wrong with my code??

If there isn't anything wrong with my code:

- How do I get my inline code to override the embedded style?

HTML

```
<div id="buttonDiv1" style="float:left;"><button id="btn1">Change units</button></div>
<div id="buttonDiv1" style="float:left; display:none;"><button id="btn2">Change units</button></div>
<div id="buttonDiv1" style="float:left; display:none;"><button id="btn3">Change units</button></div>
<input id="text" style="float:left;"></input>

<div onChange="jsfunction()">
<div style="float: left">Type: <select id="typeSelector">
  <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;"></option>
  <option value="1">Instrumental Cables</option>
  <option value="2">Erected Piping Materials</option>
  <option value="3">Electric Cables</option>
</select>
    </div></div>

<div id="container" class="cont" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

JS

```
    function jsfunction(){
//Get from user which chart to display
var val = document.getElementById("typeSelector");

if(val.value==1){
document.getElementById("btn1").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("btn2").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("btn3").style.display="none";
}
else if(val.value==2){
document.getElementById("btn1").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("btn2").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("btn3").style.display="none";
}
else{
document.getElementById("btn1").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("btn2").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("btn3").style.display="block";
}
}
```

JSfiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4T4pb/1/

Edit: It appears there was a problem with my demo code so I affixed the actual code

Comment: You mispelled .style. in js, check your console next time.
Css-tricks.com will tell you all about css specificity: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: @Brunis after fixing that yes, there was no problem with the demo code. However there is a problem with my real code, see updated post

Comment: You are violating html all over the place, id's has be unique, stop floating everything left, everything is naturally placed from left to right. The problem is your display: none; is on the outer div, but you are changing the buttons in js. So get rid of all the extra junk and it's easier not to select the wrong elements :)  Event attributes are lowercase, and put the onchange event on the select item which is the one you expect a change from. I think that should get you started :)

Comment: @Brunis Ahhhh ok that makes a lot of sense. Post an answer so I can select it as correct please :D

Comment: I moved my suggestions to an answer and edited your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the excess div's and their float layout and used display: inline; on your buttons, so they don't break the line:

Sorry, have to paste html here, otherwise i can't link a fiddle:

```
<button id="btn1">Change units</button>
<button id="btn2" style="display: none;">Change units</button>
<button id="btn3" style="display: none;">Change units</button>
<input id="text"></input>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4T4pb/2/

That should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
function func(){
    document.getElementById("change").stlye.display="none !important";
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks - didn't know you could add !important to inline styles.

Comment: still mispelled. please dont mark invalid code as an answer.